# Hostname-independent Yesod application

Tags: haskell, vhosts, yesod

This is a very simple question: How do I run a Yesod application that can handle multiple hosts at the same time?

A default Yesod setup can handle incoming connections from any host, but all URLs are rendered with `approot` prepended to them. Overriding `joinPath` in the Yesod instance declaration would be possible, if there was a way of storing the current domain so that it is available to that function, but there is not.

The method described on [this wiki page](http://www.yesodweb.com/wiki/Domain-based%20routing) works, but is very hackish, since it forces routes to take an additional `domain` parameter (since I don't have a static set of domains to match against). For practical purposes (because I have a lot of routes, some of which are domain-independent), it would be better to have a solution that left routes untouched, since it's possible to still get the host name from the WAI request info inside of a handler function.

I use things that require absolute URLs (e.g. email, RSS, XML APIs) so `approot _ = ""` is not an option.

I don't and can't know all of the host names, that need to be supported, at compile-time.

So, how do I render URLs so that they use the host name of the incoming request, and not the `approot` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to include the actual domain name in the foundation type, and use a middleware that farms out to the appropriate application depending on the Request, spawning new ones as necessary. However, this feels too heavy-weight.

I want to leave approot as-is, since it fits the general case, but perhaps we can add an extra method approotRequest that would be given the `Request` value as well. I'd like to move this discussion to the list.

**Update**: Change already landed in Git: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/commit/4dd9880389e3b61f976e44525ae97831ec578a17

Comment: I will be following the discussion, and would appreciate an update to this answer (for other users) once a solution is in the repos. Thanks!